# How to convert vector into distance matrix based on two 'name' vectors

Tags: r

I have used the tNST method from NST package in R. It returns a large list which include 'name1' (character),'name2'(character) and D.ij (double). I extract these vectors and want to convert them into a distance matrix (see below):

Input:

```
`name1`
#[1] "2008" "2009" "2010" "2009" "2010" "2010"

`name2`
#[1] "2007" "2007" "2007" "2008" "2008" "2009"


'D.ij'
#[1] 0.107 0.291 0.191 0.303 0.156 0.212
```

Expected Output:

```
  #       2007      2008      2009
  #2008  0.107                    
  #2009  0.291     0.303          
  #2010  0.191     0.156     0.212
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to construct it as a matrix in base.

```r
x <- list(name1 = c("2008", "2009", "2010", "2009", "2010", "2010"),
          name2 = c("2007", "2007", "2007", "2008", "2008", "2009"),
          D.ij = c(0.107, 0.291, 0.191, 0.303, 0.156, 0.212))

x_names <- sort(unique(c(x$name1, x$name2)))

m <- matrix(NA, nrow = length(x_names), ncol = length(x_names),
            dimnames = list(x_names, x_names))
m[lower.tri(m)] <- x$D.ij
as.dist(m)

#       2007  2008  2009
# 2008 0.107    NA    NA
# 2009 0.291 0.303    NA
# 2010 0.191 0.156 0.212
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried this one, but the m is not a distance matrix. After applying as.dist(m), the value is missing.

Comment: Check the edit. I think that should do it.

Comment: Yes, it is what I want! Appreciate!

Answer (score 2):

`tidyverse` way of doing it.

```r
list1 <- list(name1 = c('2008', 2009, 2010L, 2009L, 2010L, 2010L),
              name2 = c('2007', 2007L, 2007L, 2008L, 2008L, 2009L),
              D.ij = c(0.107, 0.291, 0.191, 0.303, 0.156, 0.212))

list1
#> $name1
#> [1] "2008" "2009" "2010" "2009" "2010" "2010"
#> 
#> $name2
#> [1] "2007" "2007" "2007" "2008" "2008" "2009"
#> 
#> $D.ij
#> [1] 0.107 0.291 0.191 0.303 0.156 0.212
library(tidyverse)

map_dfc(list1, ~.x) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = name1, names_from = name2, values_from = D.ij)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>   name1 `2007` `2008` `2009`
#>   <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1 2008   0.107 NA     NA    
#> 2 2009   0.291  0.303 NA    
#> 3 2010   0.191  0.156  0.212
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>